# <select> tag in react not changing when selecting option

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component in my react app (named `<Dropdown/>`) that has a `<select>` tag inside. For the most part, things work normally, but whenever I select one of the options, instead of having the `<select>` change and display the picked option, it just defaults back to the original value. I have no clue what's going on and help would be appreciated.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Dropdown.css";

export default function Dropdown(props) {
    let flavorTexts = props.data;
    return(
        <select className="listDrop" onChange={props.onChange}>
            {flavorTexts.map((entry) => <option className="listElement" value={{lang: entry.language.name, ver: entry.version.name}}>{entry.language.name} — {entry.version.name}</option>)}
        </select>
    );
}
```

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../../App.css'
import Dropdown from '../buttons/Dropdown';

function Search() {
  const [flavorVersion, setFlavorVersion] = useState({lang: 'en', ver: 'x'});

  const versionHandler = (selection) => {
    setFlavorVersion(selection);
  }
(...)
      return (
      <>
        (...)
            {data.description.filter((entry) => entry.language.name === flavorVersion.lang && entry.version.name === flavorVersion.ver).map(entry => <p className="dataEntry">{entry.flavor_text}</p>)}
(...)
        <Dropdown data={data.description} onChange={(e) => versionHandler(e.target.value)}/>
      </>
    )
(...)
```

Comment: You should show us what your onChange function does.

Comment: consider it done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. The issue was actually that I was re-rendering the main component every time the selection changed and thus resetting the dropdown. *My bad*. Thanks for the help XP

Answer (score 2):

You need to use value on your select tag, `value={selected}`

```
import React from "react";
import "./Dropdown.css";


export default function Dropdown(data, onChange, selected) {
    let flavorTexts = data.data;
    console.log('dropdown got: ', flavorTexts);
    return(
        <select className="listDrop" onChange={onChange} value={selected}>
            {flavorTexts.map((entry) => <option className="listElement" value={{lang: entry.language.name, ver: entry.version.name}}>{entry.language.name} — {entry.version.name}</option>)}
        </select>
    );
}
```

selected parameter should come from your `state`, the function `onChange` should control this state

This is a clear example to handle the state of select input
(`useEffect` is only to see the result of update the state)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const options = [
  { id: 1, name: 'option 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'option 2' },
];

export const Form = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({ selected: '' });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(form);
  }, [form]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setForm(form => ({ ...form, [name]: value }));
  };

  const handleSave = () => {};
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSave}>
      <div>
        <select name='selected' value={form.selected} onChange={handleChange}>
          <option value=''>Select Option</option>
          {options.map(option => (
            <option key={option.id} value={option.name}>
              {option.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

React's Documentation has this example: [Documentation](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen (and done it myself) selected automatically assign its value to the selected option, though... Is this specific to my code for some reason? 

In any case, is there a best practice way to take the value from the selected option to assign it to the `<select>` tag?

Comment: Yes, i will modificate my previous answer to put a clear example to you.

Comment: got it here dude, my bad